# Draw a polyline with a linear gradient along it's stroke width in GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+, gradient

Is it possible to draw a polyline that has a linear gradient along it's stroke width? That is, if you have a gradient with black on 0 and 100% and white 50%, the black will always be on the edge of the line and the white in the middle, regardless of the angle. Think of it as some sort of 3D pipes. Of course, the line will have a stroke width of at least 10px. All the questions here ask how to fill a line between it's ends. I'm definitely not interested in that. I'm working in C# using GDI+, can be any .NET version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

[image: Screenshot]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode=SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        DrawPipe(e.Graphics, 10f, new PointF(10, 10), new PointF(250, 80), Color.White, Color.Black);

        DrawPipe(e.Graphics, 10f, new PointF(15, 60), new PointF(280, 120), Color.BlueViolet, Color.Black);
    }

    private void DrawPipe(Graphics g, float width, PointF p1, PointF p2, Color mid_color, Color edge_color)
    {
        SizeF along=new SizeF(p2.X-p1.X, p2.Y-p1.Y);
        float mag=(float)Math.Sqrt(along.Width*along.Width+along.Height*along.Height);
        along=new SizeF(along.Width/mag, along.Height/mag);
        SizeF perp=new SizeF(-along.Height, along.Width);

        PointF p1L=new PointF(p1.X+width/2*perp.Width, p1.Y+width/2*perp.Height);
        PointF p1R=new PointF(p1.X-width/2*perp.Width, p1.Y-width/2*perp.Height);
        PointF p2L=new PointF(p2.X+width/2*perp.Width, p2.Y+width/2*perp.Height);
        PointF p2R=new PointF(p2.X-width/2*perp.Width, p2.Y-width/2*perp.Height);

        GraphicsPath gp=new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddLines(new PointF[] { p1L, p2L, p2R, p1R});
        gp.CloseFigure();

        Region region=new Region(gp);
        using(LinearGradientBrush brush=new LinearGradientBrush(
            p1L, p1R, Color.Black, Color.Black))
        {                
            ColorBlend color_blend=new ColorBlend();
            color_blend.Colors=new Color[] { edge_color, mid_color, edge_color };
            color_blend.Positions=new float[] { 0f, 0.5f, 1f };
            brush.InterpolationColors=color_blend;
            g.FillRegion(brush, region);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

An alternative is to use a `PathGradientBrush`

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddLines(new PointF[] { p1, p1L, p2L, p2, p2R, p1R });
gp.CloseFigure();

Region region = new Region(gp);
using (PathGradientBrush brush = new PathGradientBrush(gp))
{
    brush.CenterColor = mid_color;
    brush.SurroundColors = new Color[] 
    {
        mid_color, edge_color,edge_color,mid_color,edge_color,edge_color
    };          
    g.FillRegion(brush, region);
}
```

**Edit 2**

To make the edges smoother use some alpha transparency:

```
using(LinearGradientBrush brush=new LinearGradientBrush(
    p1L, p1R, Color.Black, Color.Black))
{
    ColorBlend color_blend=new ColorBlend();
    color_blend.Colors=new Color[] { 
        Color.FromArgb(0, edge_color), edge_color, mid_color, 
        edge_color, Color.FromArgb(0, edge_color) };
    color_blend.Positions=new float[] { 0f, 0.1f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 1f };
    brush.InterpolationColors=color_blend;
    g.FillRegion(brush, region);
}
```

[image: Screenshot2]

**Edit 3**
With some artifacts multiple lines are drawing, by rendering circles between then first and then the lines

```
    private void DrawPipes(Graphics g, float width, PointF[] points, Color mid_color, Color edge_color)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gp.AddEllipse(points[i].X - width / 2, points[i].Y - width / 2, width, width);

                using (PathGradientBrush brush = new PathGradientBrush(gp))
                {
                    brush.CenterColor = mid_color;
                    brush.SurroundColors = new Color[] { edge_color };
                    brush.CenterPoint = points[i];
                    g.FillPath(brush, gp);
                }
            }
            if (i > 0)
            {
                DrawPipe(g, width, points[i - 1], points[i], mid_color, edge_color);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I'm quite tired now to check it out but I'll do it tomorrow. But I have a question left: can you apply this to a polyline? I believe it will not be nice to do it on the corners, where the gradient should somehow curve. Anyways, this is a great answer, thanks a lot!